# Column histograms in Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Say I have a dataframe like the following:

```
     A B C D
s1   1 2 4 2
s2   2 1 4 3
s3   1 4 1 3
```

I would like to get a **bar plot that shows the histogram of values per column**. That is, a bar plot that shows **histograms per column** next to each other in the x axis, with spacing between the histograms (columns). In other words, it would be a two-level bar chart, where for each column in the dataframe we have bars representing the histogram of the column.

In case it matters, we can assume that the number of possible values each column has is known and constant for every column (e.g. range `[0,5]`)

When I try doing:

```
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

I get something completely different from what I want (the x ticks correspond to the rows, instead of   [`columns: [value0, value1, valueN]`). The closest "in spirit" to what I want is is:

```
df.plot(kind='density')
```

But I am looking for a histogram-like description per column, more than an overlay of PDFs.

## Update

Hopefully an example helps. I am looking for something like this plot below, ([code here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)) but instead of showing two scores per group, it would show a **histogram of values per column in my dataframe**:

[image]

Comment: In a box plot the X-axis contains categorical data. So the scale doesn't mean anything. In general, different series will differ in their range of values, and so what exactly do you want to convey with the x axis? Rescale to constant size? If so, why not just do multiple plots? If not rescaled, how do you envision the X-axis working?

Answer (score 1):

This presentation doesn't rescale, it horizontally translates the individual histograms so that they don't overlap and then labels the X-axis with the column names (at median values) rather than represent scale.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy.random import randn
sample = 1000
df = DataFrame(randn(sample, 8))
accum1 = 0
accum2 = 0
spacer = 1
MyTics = []    
for colname in df.columns:
    TransformedValues = df[colname] - accum1 + accum2
    MyTics.extend([TransformedValues.median()])
    axs = (TransformedValues).hist()
    accum1 += df[colname].min()  
    accum2 += df[colname].max() + spacer    
axs.set_xticks(MyTics)
axs.set_xticklabels(df.columns)
```

[image: Resulting multi-historgram picture]

Answer (score 0):

There is numpy's [histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) function, and matplotlib's [histogram plotting function 'hist'](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist).

Comment: Thanks. I certainly know that. What I want is to plot multiple `histograms` (one for each column) next to each other. It is technically a bar chart (with multiple bars per column representing a histgram wihin each column).

Comment: This answer is no better than a link only answer, can you elaborate more with example code and an image, also show this can be used with pandas like the OP is asking

Comment: weemattisnot and @EdChum - I have improved the OP a bit. Hopefully it' s a bit clearer now.

Comment: I see now, sorry, I misunderstood before... and aside from rolling your own, using a combination of `np.histogram()` (to get the column hights) and `plt.bar()` (to plot the interleaved bar-charts), I don't know of any quick tricks to do what you want. plt.bar() is not too difficult to make interleaved bar-charts though.. This [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) shows how, for instance.